# Line spacing doesn't line up

Tags: html

Would anyone be able to help me with the code below. I'm having a problem lining up the the email to the bottom of the picture.

I've attached an image of what the end result should be.

[image]

```html
<table style="width: 470px;" ">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="text-align: left; ">
    <td ><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/Example-Midnight_Run.png " alt="editors " width="96 " height="103 " /></td>
    <td style="width: 354.983px; ">
    <span lang="EN-CA " style="font-size:9.0pt "><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif "><span style="color:#1f497d "><strong>first line is arial 9 bold</strong></span></span></span></span></span></span><br />
    <span style="font-size:12pt "><span style="text-autospace:none "><span style="font-family:&quot;Times New Roman&quot;,serif "><span lang="EN-CA " style="font-size:9.0pt "><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif "><span style="color:#1f497d ">second line is arial 9</span></span></span></span></span></span><br />
    <a href="mailto:mail@mail.com " style="color:blue; text-decoration:underline "><strong><span lang="EN-CA " style="font-size:9.0pt "><span style="font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif "><span style="color:#0070c0 ">mail@mail.com</span></span></span></strong></a></span></span><br />
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><span style="color:#1f497d "><strong>last line is arial 9 bold</span></span></span></span></span></span><br /></strong></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: I did it for her. All information was there

Comment: Is that for a HTMLEmail? Can you explain that value `354.983px` ?

Comment: Why you use extra quotes?  `style="width: 470px;" "`

Comment: Some tutorial that I hope can help you https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/figures.en.html